# Hidden element blocking me from clicking on button

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, loops

The following code does the following:

1. Accesses a URL with the FIRST date
2. Closes the "Understanding origins" pop-up window by clicking on SKIP
3. Click on the "Download data" button
4. Opens a new tab with the NEXT date
5. closes previous tab (FIRST date URL)
6. TRIES to click on "Download data" again

The problem I have is on number 6. It gives me the "element click intercepted" error, and I assume it's because it thinks a NEW "Understanding origins" pop-up window appeared.

However, no pop-up window appears this time, unlike the first time I opened the browser (FIRST date URL). I even tried using the same code to click on the SKIP button this time, but it still gives me the same error.

How can I get around this and be able to click on the "Download data" button every time I open a new tab? Note: I'm opening thousands of tabs, one at a time here.

My code:

```
# Load Chrome driver and movement.uber.com/cities website
PATH = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

# Attributing the city name and the center-most zone code (or origin) to variables so they can be inserted in the URL later
city = 'atlanta' # Note: Atlanta might be missing data from 10/25/2018 - 10/29/2018
origin_code = '1074'
coordinates = '&lat.=33.7489&lng.=-84.4234622&z.=12'

# Open URL for the first day in the desired city (change coordinates depending on city)
driver.get('https://movement.uber.com/explore/' + city + '/travel-times/query?si' + origin_code + '&ti=&ag=taz&dt[tpb]=ALL_DAY&dt[wd;]=1,2,3,4,5,6,7&dt[dr][sd]=' + 
           '2016-01-02' + '&dt[dr][ed]=' + '2016-01-02' + '&cd=&sa;=&sdn=' + coordinates + '&lang=en-US')

# Agree to privacy preferences
priv_pref_buton = driver.find_element_by_id('privacy_pref_optin')
priv_pref_buton.click()
        
# Skip button only shows up the first time you open the Chrome browser
time.sleep(6)
skip_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/button')
skip_button.click()

                                    
# Choosing correct data parameters (Traffix Analysis Zone) and opening date bar in preparation for the calendar loop
# Zone type dropdown only shows up the first time you open the Chrome browser
zone_type_dropdown = WebDriverWait(driver, 8).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div')))
zone_type_dropdown.click()

traffic_analysis_zones = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/ul/li[2]')))
traffic_analysis_zones.click()
        

# Buttons for downloading the dataset
download_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.f5 button') # //button[contains(@data-baseweb, "button")]')
download_button.click()
time.sleep(3)

# travel_times_download = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/button[1]')
# travel_times_download.click()


# Day list and loop Solution proposed in StackOverflow
# Generating the correct URLs for each date
def getURL():
    date = datetime(2016,1,3)
    while date <= datetime(2020,3,31):
        yield ('https://movement.uber.com/explore/' + city + '/travel-times/query?si' + origin_code + '&ti=&ag=taz&dt[tpb]=ALL_DAY&dt[wd;]=1,2,3,4,5,6,7&dt[dr][sd]=' +
               date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + '&dt[dr][ed]=' + date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + '&cd=&sa;=&sdn=&lat.=33.7489&lng.=-84.4234622&z.=12&lang=en-US')
        date += timedelta(days=1)

# Perform iteration through URLs downloading the datasets for each URL
i = 0
print("urls: %i", len(list(getURL())))
for url in getURL():
    i += 1
    if i < 4:
        driver.execute_script("window.open('"+url+"', '_blank')")
        print(url)
        time.sleep(3)
        
        # Create function
        # Agree to privacy preferences
        try:
            priv_pref_buton = driver.find_element_by_id('privacy_pref_optin')
            priv_pref_buton.click()
        
        except:
            pass
        
        # Skip button only shows up the first time you open the Chrome browser
        try:
            time.sleep(6)
            skip_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.btn btn--link')
        
            skip_button.click()
            
        except:
            pass
        
        time.sleep(3)
        download_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.f5 button') # //button[contains(@data-baseweb, "button")]')
        download_button.click()
        time.sleep(1)
        
        # travel_times_download = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/button[1]')
        # travel_times_download.click()
        
        # Switch to previous tab and close it (leaving us with the newly above opened tab)
        tabs = driver.window_handles
        
        if len(tabs) > 1:
            driver.switch_to.window(tabs[0])
            driver.close()
            driver.switch_to.window(tabs[1])
```

The error is the following:

```
ElementClickInterceptedException          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-89-80ae8e1decd5> in <module>
     70         time.sleep(3)
     71         download_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.f5 button') # //button[contains(@data-baseweb, "button")]')
---> 72         download_button.click()
     73         time.sleep(1)
     74 

c:\users\i539797\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py in click(self)
     78     def click(self):
     79         """Clicks the element."""
---> 80         self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
     81 
     82     def submit(self):

c:\users\i539797\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py in _execute(self, command, params)
    631             params = {}
    632         params['id'] = self._id
--> 633         return self._parent.execute(command, params)
    634 
    635     def find_element(self, by=By.ID, value=None):

c:\users\i539797\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    319         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    320         if response:
--> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    323                 response.get('value', None))

c:\users\i539797\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <button data-baseweb="button" class="by f6 ae ah f7 f8 f9 fa fb fc fd fe ff dj fg fh cx cy c6 fi fj fk bo bn bp bm b3 cb ck c0 fl fm fn fo fp fq fr fs ft fu fv fw fx fy f5 cd fz g0 g1">...</button> is not clickable at point (212, 634). Other element would receive the click: <div>...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.105)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that your driver is still focussed on tab one.
When you open a new tab you need to change the driver to focus to it.

The intercepted click was caused by download popup on the previous tab.

**Option 1**
Change this:

```
driver.execute_script("window.open('"+url+"', '_blank')")
```

To this:

```
driver.execute_script("window.open('"+url+"', '_blank')")
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])
```

**Option 2**
Alternatively, don't use tabs.
Changing the `execute_script` to this use a singe tab works:

```
driver.execute_script("window.open('"+url+"', '_self')")
```

And actually the same as:  (which also works)

```
driver.get(url)
```

**finally**, *if using a single tab* you won't need this:

```
  # Switch to previous tab and close it (leaving us with the newly above opened tab)
        tabs = driver.window_handles
        
        if len(tabs) > 1:
            driver.switch_to.window(tabs[0])
            driver.close()
            driver.switch_to.window(tabs[1])
```

however - since tabs will now always be 1, this code shouldn't run anyway.

If tabs is an absolute must let me know and i'll have another look.

Comment: Yeah, I started to think that if it didn't work I might have to start using opening whole windows again. I only wanted to use tabs because they are faster to open and close, but I can use windows. Let me have a try... It works!! however, do you know why it is taking so long for the last window to open? Even after I removed all time.sleep(), I odn't know if the try and except are slowing it down. Is that possible?

Comment: Is the error catching needed anymore? Does it work if you remove and is it faster? Give it a go and see :-)

Comment: It works!!! I can't believe it. I really appreciate you helping me throughout all my long, boring posts. Thank you so much! IF there is one last thing I am trying to fix it's actually the time it takes for the code to perform the skip_button thing. I am currently using time.sleep(6), but whenever I try to use WebDriverWait, it doesn't work for whatever reason, no matter the value I put in the function. It works for the zone_type dropdown and traffic_analysis_zones variables though.

Comment: What expected conditions have you tried? - did you try element to be clickable ?

Comment: What do you mean by expected conditions? Well, yeah, I expect the skip button to be clickable, but I guess the whole point of the WebDriverWait function is to wait until the button is ready and then recognize it, no?

Comment: There are different expected conditions, some visible, some displayed, some clickable - in your webdriver wait you do "EC." , and your imports have expected conditions... Ec = expected conditions. All the same thing :-)  I will have a look Monday, but in the interim this is stuff you can try. (try element to be clickable) - https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Comment: Nice I will try i tout. I think the problem was that I was assigning a wrong variable. Probably. Not the first time that has happened. Rich, thank you so much for the help. Already putting the code to test and already running into "too many requests" and trying to figure out a way around it!